# Count items in table, table field enum type involved

Tags: mysql, sql, select, count, group-by

I have a basic table named `animals` with two fields `name` and `type`. The field `type` is an enum field with these values: `enum('dog','cat','horse','zebra','lion')`. I am trying to run a query and count the number of each species as well as specify the name of that species. For example an expected result will show something like this `dog=2, cat=2, etc.`. In the query below I am able to count the overall total of `animals` but not break down into amount of species and name. How could I do so? [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0cccc7/1)

Query:

```
select COUNT(type) from animals
```

Table Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE animals 
(
 name varchar(20),      
 type enum('dog','cat','horse','zebra','lion') 
 );

INSERT INTO animals
(name, type)
VALUES
('Bertha', 'horse'),
('Louis', 'cat'),
('Gina', 'cat'),
('Rafa', 'lion'),
('lilo', 'dog'),
('kilo', 'dog'),
('stripy', 'zebra');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `GROUP BY` and `COUNT` for counting animals by type.

Try this:

```
SELECT a.type, COUNT(1) AS Cnt
FROM animals a 
GROUP BY a.type;
```

Check this [**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/01c38/1)

**OUTPUT**

```
|  TYPE | CNT |
|-------|-----|
|   dog |   2 |
|   cat |   2 |
| horse |   1 |
| zebra |   1 |
|  lion |   1 |
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean

```
select type, COUNT(*) from animals
group by type
```

[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0cccc7/4)

Answer (score 1):

You can use group by type to get the count of each animal type. Here is the query for same.

SELECT `type`,COUNT(*) FROM animals
 GROUP BY `type`

type    count(*)

---

dog              2
cat              2
horse            1
zebra            1
lion             1